# Help with this component

Tags: components, identification

Can you identify this component.  I think it is a fuse.

It is 5 mm long and 2.5 mm in diameter.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a broken resistor to me..

Comment: @EugeneSh. aka "poor man's fuse"

Comment: Because of the asymmetric marking my guess would be a diode.Diodes are the only SMD components I have seen in a cylindrical houseing, but I haven't seen that much.

Comment: @NickM, consider cropping your photo better to give us a better look at the part.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen 1206 resistors can also be in cylindrical form (they are quite common in our products). But those have a lot more bands and are symmetric (in case of jumper resistors only a single black marking is in the middle).

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a diode of some sort. The case seems to be a DO-213AB plastic casing (more exactly: molded epoxy over glass body) with two marking bands. One is typically used to give information about type and polarity (the white one) and the other about voltage rating (the red one).

Question is, what type exactly. I've found for example [1N6479](http://www.vishay.com/docs/88527/1n6478.pdf) from Vishay. The markings would translate into:

1. White band: Standard recovery type
2. Red band: 100V max. DC blocking voltage

But I'm almost certain that you can find a different type with the same markings out there somewhere. If it is a working diode, you could try and measure some of it's parameters and see if it fits.